# How to add time in datetimepicker

Tags: jquery

I using plugin datetimepicker with format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss , I want add time (ex: 10 second) in it 2011-07-12 12:34:45 (45 + 10 second = 55) => result: 2011-07-12 12:34:55, I am not this ideas, Who can help me this ideas

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [TimePicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) extension to the JQuery [DatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/).